# Use wildcard in xr's externaldocument command?

Tags: xr

Is it possible to somehow tell the xr package's externaldocument command to use wildcards? Instead of:

```
\externaldocument{ch_A/figures/a}
\externaldocument{ch_A/figures/b}
\externaldocument{ch_A/figures/c}
\externaldocument{ch_B/figures/x}
\externaldocument{ch_B/figures/y}
\externaldocument{ch_B/figures/z}
```

just do

```
\externaldocument{ch_A/figures/*}
\externaldocument{ch_B/figures/*}
```

(I have pretty stable chapters but often add tikz-based, multi-page standalone files to my figures subfolders; keeping track of them manually works of course, but is a hassle).

There are a few similar questions for \graphicspath, but nothing really for xr.

Comment: LaTeX does not have access to the shell like that so it cannot resolve the `*`. You might be able to do something in `lualatex`

Comment: xr has no access to your directory and can't get a list of files. Create such a list with some external tool and then read it it in.

Comment: @HolgerKarl if your actual files also have alphabetic/numeric names, you could load them all in a loop

Comment: if your standalone files are tikz images why do they have `\label` ?

Comment: Thanks; sure, I could put a little find > externaldocuments.tex in my Makefile.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I have multiple (sometimes, 30-40) tikzpictures per standalone files. Each gets a label to be pulled in via page=\getpagerefnumber{label} option to \includegraphics. 
Actually a convenient workflow, expect that I often forget to add new standalone files to external documents :-).

Comment: If you say so:-) I wrote \includegraphics and xr and I'm surprised it works but I'm sure it does:-)

Comment: Works like a charm :-) 

Figure files have: 

\begin{tikzpicture}
\label{page:duplex:tdd}
% ... tikz stuff 
\end{tikzpicture}

and used in other file like: 
\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,page=\getpagerefnumber{page:duplex:tdd},width=0.85\textwidth]{./standalone/duplexing.pdf}